# Comparing arrays with numbers in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need a way to compare two arrays in vb.net and save result in third array:

```
Dim KonRes(3) As Integer
Dim UserRes(3) As Integer
Dim YelRed(3) As Integer

KonRes(0) = 1
KonRes(1) = 2
KonRes(2) = 3
KonRes(3) = 4

UserRes(0) = 4
UserRes(1) = 3
UserRes(2) = 2
UserRes(3) = 1
```

How to compare those arrays so in declared variable **YelRed** I should have results like this:

```
If UserRes(0) = KonRes(0) Then
YelRed(0) = 2
If UserRes(0) = KonRes(1 or 2 or 3) Then
YelRed(0) = 1
```

If UserRes(0) does not contain any number like in KonRes then  YelRed(0) should be 0. Also it should not make duplicate results, in other words if it already checked UserRes(0) = **KonRes(0)** then it should not check KonRes(0) in next check. It's not a problem to compare if those arrays are completely same, my problem is comparing each value of one array with other one, and collect results. Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't said what the expected result is. You want to store 0 if the number is not in second array but what do you want to store if the number is there? If the arrays dont contain duplicates you could use `HashSet(Of Int32)`

Comment: Expected results: If UserRes(0) = KonRes(0) that mean they are in same position in two arrays, then YelRed(0) = 2, if UserRes(0) = KonRes(1,2,3) so number is there and but not in same position, so YelRed(0) =1 and if the number is not in secod array.

Comment: With the duplicate results condition, should it NOT check KonRes(0) only if it was set to 2 (what about if it was set to 1)? Neither of the current answers check this.

Comment: Can you give us the expected output? Is this thinking correct:  if UserRes has values (1,1,2,2) and KonRes(1,1,3,2), then it should return (2,2,1,0), not (2,1,1,2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few basic ways of checking for a value in an integer array. The first is to manually search by looping through each value in the array, which may be what you want if you need to do complicated comparisons.

Second is the .Contains() method. It is simpler to use but will only give you a Boolean indicating whether the value is in the array or not. Example:

```
If KonRes.Contains(UserRes(0)) Then YelRed(0) = 1
```

Lastly, there's the IndexOf() function. It searches for a match and returns the index of a match if found, or one below the lower bound of the array if not (-1 for typical 0-based arrays). As I understand your needs from your comments above, this code should do the trick:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 3
    Select Case IndexOf(KonRes, UserRes(i))
        Case i   'Matching postion
            YelRed(i) = 2
        Case -1   'No match found
            YelRed(i) = 0
        Case Else   'Match found at another position
            YelRed(i) = 1
    End Select
Next i
```

EDIT: I misunderstood the qualification about duplicates until @Sastreen clarified it. Here's a rewrite tailored to not count the same index as a match twice:

```
Dim processed(3) As Boolean
For i As Integer = 0 To 3
    YelRed(i) = 0
    If KonRes(i) = UserRes(i) And Not processed(i) Then
        processed(i) = True
        YelRed(i) = 2
    Else
        For j As Integer = 0 To 3
            If KonRes(j) = UserRes(i) Then
                processed(j) = True
                YelRed(i) = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This doesn't make sure that it doesn't return "duplicates", as the question asked.

Comment: Nice job with the fix to duplicates! I think that's what he wanted it to be like. This is why I had used two for loops in the beginning (I think it would be hard to do with IndexOf).

Comment: Yeah. I wasn't 100% sure I completely understood everything he was asking for originally, which is why I mentioned manually looping through the array might be best for more complicated comparisons. IndexOf was cleaner based on my original understanding of the question but complicated the code unnecessarily once you clarified. I still wanted to explain all the options because people will have this question again and find this answer and many of them will likely have slightly different needs than Dalibor.

Comment: That's totally reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

> If `UserRes(0) = KonRes(0)` that mean they are in same position in two
>   arrays, then `YelRed(0) = 2`, if `UserRes(0) = KonRes(1,2,3)` so number is
>   there and but not in same position, so `YelRed(0) =1` and if the number
>   is not in second array it must be 0.

Use a `For`-Loop:

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To KonRes.Length - 1
    If KonRes(i) = UserRes(i) Then
        ' Same position '
        YelRed(i) = 2
    ElseIf UserRes.Contains(KonRes(i)) Then
        ' Other  position '
        YelRed(i) = 1
    Else
        ' Not contained '
        YelRed(i) = 0
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes sure that it doesn't return "duplicates", as the question asked.

Comment: @Sastreen: what kind of duplicates? It just loops the `KonRes`-array. I guess that's just a language issue and OP doesn't mean _duplicates_ but avoid cheching the same array-index multiple times. `UserRes.Contains` checks the same array index twice but that's not a problem at all, because i have used `ElseIf`.

Comment: As I understand it (may be wrong), if UserRes has values (1,1,2,2) and KonRes(1,1,3,2), then it should return (2,2,1,0), not (2,1,1,2). So the second value of 1 will find the second index of 1 in KonRes, not the first (as a contains would do).

Comment: But yours will give a 2 to this first 1 (since it finds the 1 at index 1), and then a 1 to the second 1 (since it *again* finds the 1 at index 1, rather than index 2)

Comment: You mean that he wants to take the number of occurrences into account?

Comment: In a way, yes. It seems he wants to ignore a number as soon as a "2" value is reached. I could definitely be understanding this wrong. Do you see his comment about the duplicates? What do you make of that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `For` loops to go through the two arrays to compare, and then use `Exit For` to leave at any time.

The `indicesToIgnore` is for making sure it does not "make duplicate results" (this is harder to achieve with the `IndexOf` and `contains` methods).

> Also it should not make duplicate results, in other words if it already checked UserRes(0) = KonRes(0) then it should not check KonRes(0) in next check.

```
Dim indicesToIgnore as New List(Of Integer)

'go through first array
For i as Integer = 0 to UserRes.length - 1 Step 1
    'go through second array
    For j as Integer = 0 to KonRes.length- 1 Step 1
        'if the values are equal, check whether same index, then exit for
        If (Not indicesToIgnore.contains(j) AndAlso UserRes(i) = KonRes(j)) Then
            If i=j Then
                YelRed(i) = 2
                indicesToIgnore.add(j)
            Else
                YelRed(i) = 1
            End If   
        Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

You don't need to set `YelRed(i)` to 0 at any time because it defaults as this. You just need to make sure `YelRed` has the same size as the other arrays.

If you also want it to not look at the KonRes value (for duplicates) if it contains it at a different index, simply add `indicesToIgnore.add(j)` at the end of the `Else` (after `YelRed(i) = 1`) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the job, if KonRes(0) = UserRes(0) then YelRed(0) = 1 else YelRed(0) = 2

```
    Dim KonRes(3) As Integer
    Dim UserRes(3) As Integer
    Dim YelRed(3) As Integer

    KonRes(0) = 1
    KonRes(1) = 2
    KonRes(2) = 3
    KonRes(3) = 4

    UserRes(0) = 4
    UserRes(1) = 2
    UserRes(2) = 2
    UserRes(3) = 1

    Dim Uindex As Integer = 0
    For Each item In UserRes
        Dim Kindex As Integer = 0
        For Each i In KonRes
            If item = i Then
                If Kindex = Uindex Then
                    YelRed(Uindex) = 1
                Else
                    YelRed(Uindex) = 2
                End If
            End If
            Kindex += 1
        Next
        Uindex += 1
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't told us what the output should be. It's a bit confusing. In my case, it will be {1, 1, 0, 0}. If was to be done with 2 for loop. On that loops everything in KonRes while the other only loop what wasn't checked yet in UserRes.

```
    For k As Integer = 0 To KonRes.Length - 1
        If KonRes(k) = UserRes(k) Then
            YelRed(k) = 2
        Else
            YelRed(k) = 0

            For u As Integer = k + 1 To UserRes.Length - 1
                If KonRes(k) = UserRes(u) Then
                    YelRed(k) = 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the comparison from the array.

Dim iNextActivityTypeCd As Integer = 18400
Dim activities() As Integer = {1,18400, 2300, 3423}

If activities.Contains(iNextActivityTypeCd) Then
   Dim foo = 1
End If